# Run a Gitlab job in a pipeline only if changes outside a given path

Tags: gitlab-ci

Our project contains a lot of documentation, which is written in Asciidoctor and published to our Confluence.

I would skip some jobs, if only the documentation changed. But I don't know how I can express this in the `rules/changes` section of our job definition.

How can I express that I want to run a job only if all changes are outside a certain folder?

I am aware of the `except` clause, but the current documentation states, that this clause if more or less deprecated and the suggest to uses `rules/changes` only.